# How to add a picture frame and insert the text in the image?

Tags: delphi, text, frame, image

This is what I need: Program for quicker making fun posters for facebook page. 
Posters have text, picture and frame (white line and black background).
In this case, I want to insert logo on poster (png image).

Depending on picture size, dimensions of frame (who in this case consits of two shapes) must automaticly be resized for picture.

[image]

How to save poster from that image from link (2 shape components, 2 image components, 2 labels) as picture?

How to accomplish this? What to use, where to begin?

I hope that this question will not be removed.

Comment: What Delphi version do you use?

Comment: You IMHO should not use Shapes,Panels,Labels etc.
You can use Canvas e.g. of Bitmaps or HDC with GDI+ for unlimited opinions. It isn't to difficult and you would be unlimited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put all the frames, shapes and pictures inside a new TPanel (named MainPanel in my sample), then you could use:

```
procedure savePanelAsImage(fpPanel: tPanel; fpFileName: string);
var
   img: TBitmap;
begin
   img := TBitmap.Create;
   try
     img.Width := fpPanel.Width;
     img.Height := fpPanel.Height;
     fpPanel.PaintTo(img.Canvas, 0, 0);
     img.SaveToFile(fpFileName);
   finally
     img.Free;
   end
end;
```

**Usage:**

```
savePanelAsImage(MainPanel, 'd:\someFolder\image001.bmp');
```

**Notes:**

- This is VCL based sample;
- To save the image in other format (rather in BMP) use: TPngImage (Vcl.Imaging.pngImage) or TJPEGImage (Vcl.Imaging.jpeg);
- If you use FireMonkey (>= Delphi XE2) you can take advantage of someParentComponent.MakeScreenShot();
- The resulting image will have the same size as the tPanel.

For better results / flexibility I would suggest using [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/) library for Delphi (it supports layers, image re-sizing etc.).

[image: Example form]

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: Nice answer. Bonus points for providing a working example with screenshots and suggesting alternatives

Comment: I use Delphi XE3. Thank you for answer, @WoutervanNifterik has said all. :)