# How to reduce the size of JPG file?

Tags: delphi, size, jpeg, reduce

Few days ago I asked this question and got the answer:
[How to add a picture frame and insert the text in the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238076/how-to-add-a-picture-frame-and-insert-the-text-in-the-image)

Now, when I save content from TPanel (1x shape, 1x TImage, 2x TLabel) as JPG file,
size of that JPG file is increased from 20kb, wich is size of picture in TImage, to 620kb.

Dimensions are almost same. Original JPG file 320x320, new JPG picture 361x440.

So, how to reduce that size?

This is answer for first question, from @iPath, so that is how new JPG file is created:

```
procedure TForm1.SavePanelAsImage;
var
 img: TBitmap;
begin
 img := TBitmap.Create;
 try
  img.Width := fpPanel.Width;
  img.Height := fpPanel.Height;
  fpPanel.PaintTo(img.Canvas, 0, 0);
  img.SaveToFile(fpFileName);
 finally
  img.Free;
end;
end;
```

Comment: A Bitmap file is being created! In the Notes section in my answer I mentioned you have to use TJPEGImage to convert the bitmap to Jpeg. My example saves a bitmap, as @David-Heffernan clarified ;)

Comment: Be careful with this, BTW.  JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm, which means that if you save an image and load it again, you don't get back the exact same image.  So if you edit it multiple times, saving as JPEG each time, your image will suffer from multiple generational losses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you have saved is not a JPEG image. You have saved a Windows bitmap. That has no compression at all. It happens to have the `.jpg` extension, but that doesn't make the file itself be a JPEG.

You need to use `TJPEGImage` to save the file. Control the compression by using the [`CompressionQuality`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.CompressionQuality) property. Once you have your image in a bitmap, transfer it to a JPEG

```
uses
  jpeg;

procedure TForm1.SavePanelAsImage;
var
  img: TBitmap;
  JpegImage: TJPEGImage;
begin
  img := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    img.Width := fpPanel.Width;
    img.Height := fpPanel.Height;
    fpPanel.PaintTo(img.Canvas, 0, 0);
    JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      JpegImage.CompressionQuality := ...;//you decide the value
      JpegImage.Assign(img);
      JpegImage.SaveToFile(fpFileName);
    finally
      JpegImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    img.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

The file is being saved as a Bitmap, and *not* as a JPEG.

Even at "extremely good quality", a JPEG will not be that size.

However, a 32-bit Bitmap (without RLE) *will be* - 361 * 440 * 4 (bytes/pixel) ~ 640k

Answer (score 4):

```
implementation
uses Jpeg;


procedure SaveBMPasJPG(bmp:TBitmap; const FileName:String;Quality:Integer=90);
var
  jpg:TJpegImage;
begin
   jpg:=TJpegImage.Create;
   try
     jpg.CompressionQuality := Quality;
     jpg.Assign(bmp);
     jpg.SaveToFile(FileName);
   finally
     jpg.Free;
   end;

end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Kernel Bulk image resizer tool for resizing your image single or multiple at once.